# Refactor lots of if's and comparisions inside them with similar strings to match

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

This is the example I have made, about versions that should be use to rollback the O.S and to install it depending on the version already installed in a PC, the only restriction is that it should be in .NET 2.0

What is the best way to refactor this code taking into account that  the versions have first part of the strings in common.

In the case of version "8.40.1" is where matters the (text) inside, they are different, not like the others that are just different names for the same version.

```
//previous
if (version.Equals("8.80.0(PrinterData)") || version.Equals("8.80.0(PrinterData)(Box)") || version.Equals("8.80.0(Box)") || version.Equals("8.80.0"))
{
    myPCVersion = "8.40.1(PrinterData)";
}
else if (version.Equals("8.80.0(CNA)") || version.Equals("8.80.0(CNA)(Box)") || version.Equals("8.80.0(Box)") || version.Equals("8.80.0"))
{
    myPCVersion = "8.40.1(CNA)";
}
else if (version.Equals("7.50.0(Windows 7 Home)") || version.Equals("7.50.0(Windows 7 Home)(Box)") || version.Equals("7.50.0(Box)") || version.Equals("7.50.0"))
{
    myPCVersion = "7.0.b(Windows 7 Home)";
}
else if (version.Equals("6.50.0(Windows 8 Pro)") || version.Equals("6.50.0(Windows 8 Pro)(Box)") || version.Equals("6.50.0(Box)") || version.Equals("6.50.0"))
{
    myPCVersion = "6.42.1(Windows 8 Pro)";
}
else if (version.Equals("2.50.0(Home)") || version.Equals("2.50.0(Home)(Box)") || version.Equals("2.50.0(Box)") || version.Equals("2.50.0"))
{
    myPCVersion = "2.4.0(Home)";
}




//now
if (version.Equals("8.40.1(PrinterData)") || version.Equals("8.40.1(PrinterData)(Box)") || version.Equals("8.40.1(Box)") || version.Equals("8.40.1"))
{
    myPCVersion = actionToRun.Equals("Install") ? "8.80.0(PrinterData)" : "8.40.1(PrinterData)";
}
else if (version.Equals("8.40.1(CNA)") || version.Equals("8.40.1(CNA)(Box)") || version.Equals("8.40.1(Box)") || version.Equals("8.40.1"))
{
    myPCVersion = actionToRun.Equals("Install") ? "8.80.0(CNA)" : "8.40.1(CNA)";
}
else if (version.Equals("7.0.b(Windows 7 Home)") || version.Equals("7.0.b(Windows 7 Home)(Box)") || version.Equals("7.0.b(Box)") || version.Equals("7.0.b"))
{
    myPCVersion = actionToRun.Equals("Install") ? "7.50.0(Windows 7 Home)" : "7.0.b(Windows 7 Home)";
}
else if (version.Equals("6.42.1(Windows 8 Pro)") || version.Equals("6.42.1(Windows 8 Pro)(Box)") || version.Equals("6.42.1(Box)") || version.Equals("6.42.1"))
{
    myPCVersion = actionToRun.Equals("Install") ? "6.50.0(Windows 8 Pro)" : "6.42.1(Windows 8 Pro)";
}
else if (version.Equals("2.4.0(Home)") || version.Equals("2.4.0(Home)(Box)") || version.Equals("2.4.0(Box)") || version.Equals("2.4.0"))
{
    myPCVersion = actionToRun.Equals("Install") ? "2.50.0(Home)" : "2.4.0(Home)";
}
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("New Version: " + myPCVersion);
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is the best way to refactor this code taking into account that  the versions have first part of the strings in common, I'll add this

Comment: @dracarons your question/code make no sense.  Why are you checking in multiple if statements `version.Equals("8.40.1")` for example?

Comment: @maccettura because, the string "version" comes from a config file from the PC, and I take into account that this may be different from PC's, it may return "8.40.1(cna), 8.40.1(cna)(box" and all of them but at the end, is the same version "8.40.1"

Comment: @dracarons That still does not make sense.  You are checking `if (version == "8.40.1(PrinterData)" || version == "8.40.1(PrinterData)(Box)" || version == "8.40.1(Box)" || version == "8.40.1")` then on the very next line you are checking `if (version == "8.40.1(CNA)" || version == "8.40.1(CNA)(Box)" || version == "8.40.1(Box)" || version == "8.40.1")`.  You see how in both you check for `"8.40.1(Box)"` and `"8.40.1"`?  This is one single variable, if it didnt equal `"8.40.1(Box)"` or `"8.40.1"` in the first if statement, its certainly not going to equal it in the next.

Comment: yes, @maccettura, I forgot to clerify that, only in those cases "8.40.1" is where matters the (text) inside, they are different, not like the others that are just different names for the same version.

Comment: Use a Dictionary

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble I've done that but, when it comes to find the right version to install or rollback?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you could nest the Dictionaries, as it looks like your second set of ifs has a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>` look to it

Answer (score 1):

As many people have said a dictionary is the type of data structure that is used to refactor if / switch statements.  Here is something I mocked up that might get you close to what you need.

```
public class VersionMap
{
    public String Install { get; private set; }
    public String Rollback { get; private set; }

    public VersionMap(String install, String rollback)
    {
        Install = install;
        Rollback = rollback;
    }
}

public String GetVersion(String version, String actionToRun)
{
    var _8800PrinterData = new VersionMap("8.80.0(PrinterData)", "8.40.1(PrinterData)");
    var _8800CNA = new VersionMap("8.80.0(CNA)", "8.40.1(CNA)");

    var map = new Dictionary<string, VersionMap>
    {
        { "8.40.1(PrinterData)", _8800PrinterData },
        { "8.40.1(PrinterData)(Box)", _8800PrinterData },
        { "8.40.1(Box)", _8800PrinterData },
        { "8.40.1", _8800PrinterData },
        { "8.40.1(CNA)", _8800CNA },
        { "8.40.1(CNA)(Box)", _8800CNA },
        { "8.40.1(Box)",_8800CNA },
    };

    return actionToRun.Equals("Install") ? map[version].Install : map[version].Rollback;
}
```

There might need to be modifications to get this to work in 2.0, I don't know the exact syntax differences for 2.0

Edit: I would also recommend that before you start making changes, add some unit tests that will ensure your current functionality does not change as you refactor.